# Maven does not pick up tests in spring boot app

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

In a spring boot app, I have a test class as such

```
class UserInfoControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;
    @Mock
    private Principal principal;
    private UserInfoController subject;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        //before each code
    }

    @Test
    void shouldReturnXYZ() {
       //test code
    }

    //more tests
}
```

The tests in these class are picked up by IntelliJ Idea, when for example, choosing the `Run -> Run with coverage` option.

But when I run `mvn test` or `mvn clean test`, none of these tests are picked up. How do I solve this issue?

**Edit:** Here is `pom.xml`

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>foo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Foo</name>
<description>Bar</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Dalston.SR4</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- spring boot and dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <!-- For testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I removed dependencies that are not related to testing, such as `lombok`, `gson` etc from the above file to keep the question small.

Comment: Can you post the folder structure?

Comment: @user6690200 I have marked the `test -> java` directory as test sources root. But I don't think this is an issue, as maven should be agnostic to the IDE.

Comment: Where have you located your test? `src/test/java/` ? BTW: Good reason why you have made the test package private? Make it public ?

Comment: @khmarbaise tests are in `src/test/java`. I made the test class package private as IntelliJ was complaining the classes were unnecessarily public. It doesn't make any difference if I make the class public.

Comment: please add your POM.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Done, see the edit.

Comment: Can you please make a sample project with the above class on Github so we can take a look....

Answer (score 2):

This is an "issue" with using Junit5 and Surefire you need to specify the the provider for Surefire to be able to run the Junit5 tests,

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit-platform-surefire-provider</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

It works within IntelliJ as IntelliJ has native support for Junit5 currently, same with Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. But it's not exactly correct. I found another question of which this is duplicate, although I'd have never found that if not for this answer. I'll close this as duplicate so that anyone who googles for this also finds the other one.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that you should import  `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead of ` org.junit.Test`